# Como posso passar vários parâmetros em uma solicitação HTTP em Angular 6?

Tags: typescript, angular-6

Abaixo eu tenho minha classe de serviços, mas ao realizar a pesquisa com parâmetros, os parâmetros não são passados ​​para o pedido. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import * as moment from 'moment';

export interface LancamentoFiltro{

  descricao: string;
  dataVencimentoInicio: Date;
  dataVencimentoFim: Date;

}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LancamentoService {

  lancamentosUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/lancamentos';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  pesquisar(filter: LancamentoFiltro) : Observable<any>{

    let params = new HttpParams();
    let headers = new  HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic dmFsZGlvbm9yanVuaW9yQG91dGxvb2suY29tOkJ3aTI4MDI4MSo=');

    if(filter.descricao){ 
      params.set('descricao', filter.descricao);
    } 

    if(filter.dataVencimentoInicio){
      params.set('dataVencimentoDe', moment(filter.dataVencimentoInicio).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));//uso a biblioteca moment para formatar a data
    } 

    if(filter.dataVencimentoFim){
      params.set('dataVencimentoAte', moment(filter.dataVencimentoFim).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));//uso a biblioteca moment para formatar a data
    } 

    return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.lancamentosUrl}?resumo`,{headers, params});
  }
}
```

Comment: preciso passar quando houver os parâmetros para a requisição HTTP, utilizando o HttpParams, porem usando a forma acima, os parametros não são passados.

Comment: está em Portugues

Comment: obrigado por revisar o texto, e desculpe, não possuo muito costume no site.

Comment: Tranquilo, leia o [tour] para saber como ele funciona, e podes também acessar a [help] para obter ajuda

Comment: Faça assim: `params = params.set('descricao', filter.descricao);` faça o mesmo com os outros e veja se funciona.

Comment: Editado*
fazendo dessa forma como sugeriu o params ainda vem vazio quando passo mais de um parametro.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu sim a sua sugestão. Muito oBrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Faça assim: params = params.set('descricao', filter.descricao); faça o mesmo com >os outros e veja se funciona. – **NoobSaibot**